# how to pass every key and value of dict as arguments to other function in python

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, keyword-argument, args, hyperledger-iroha

```
def set_detail_to_user(id, key, val):
    """
    Set details to id@domain by admin
    """

    tx = iroha.transaction([iroha.command('SetAccountDetail',
                account_id=id +'@' + domain_name, key=key, value=val)
            ])
    IrohaCrypto.sign_transaction(tx, ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY)
    send_transaction_and_print_status(tx)
```

- now I want to pass a dict as arg when I call this function

```
#now when i call the function
user = new.__id.replace('-', '')
my_dict = new.__dict__
set_detail_to_user(user,every_key_in_my_dict, every_value_in_my_dict)
```

any suggestions please to call the function multiple times for each key-value pair

Comment: Do you want to call the function for all key/value pairs at once, or do you want to call it multiple times, once for each key/value pair?

Comment: call it multiple times for each key-value pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for key, value in dict.items():
        set_detail_to_user(id, key, value)
```

There are multiple ways. You can pass whole dictionary too.

Comment: thank you, worked well with simple strings, I just need to handle special characters in some values

Comment: You can handle it inside the function or preprocess the values before feeding.